# GDB attaching to a process where executable is deleted

Tags: linux, gdb

I have running process but it's executable file has got deleted. 
If I try to attach gdb I got following error

```
/home/vivek/binary/releases/20120328101511/bin/app.exe (deleted): No such file or directory.
```

How can I attach gdb to this process ?

Sample Test case:
Source code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
  for (;;){
    printf("Sleeping");
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

compile it

```
 gcc main.cc -o a.out
 gcc main.cc -o b.out
```

Run 
./a.out

Now from different terminal delete a.out. 
And fire gdb attach `pgrep a.out` file b.out 
It doesn't work.

GDB shows following error:

```
/tmp/temp/a.out (deleted): No such file or directory.
A program is being debugged already.  Kill it? (y or n) n
Program not killed.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `/proc/<pid>/exe` as the executable. It appears as a symbolic link these days, however, in the past it was possible to extract the deleted executable from it.

See [Detecting deleted executables](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_-1jwRwNaEoC&lpg=PA655&ots=KvDOs1sUUq&dq=proc%20exe%20deleted%20executable&pg=PA655#v=onepage&q&f=false).

We can use following command to attach gdb

```
gdb <path-to-binary> <pid>
```

Comment: That works under linux (I just tested it, intending to post same), I didn't see anyone mention cygwin here.

Comment: @maxim look at the command line. I'm guessing here, but it looks cygwin, not linux to me.

Comment: @littleadv: I guess you got confused by `.exe`. Absolute path in cygwin would start with `/cygdrive/c/...`.

Comment: @Maxim Yegorushkin
I have original executable at other location. Can I use that in gdb to attach on current running process ?

Comment: That should work if the binary is the same. `gdb <path-to-binary> <pid>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. GDB needs the symbol data that's in the executable and is not being loaded by the OS when running the program.

Comment: can't I specify same executable file but at different location?

Comment: but how if I give gdb process <pid> it says executable deleted. Program already debugged.

Comment: you should use the "attach" and the "file" command line options together. http://www.ofb.net/gnu/gdb/gdb_99.html#SEC99

Comment: It don't work it shows error. 
  gdb attach 335 b.out. 
/tmp/temp/a.out (deleted): No such file or directory.