# Under Linux, is it possible to gcore a process whose executable has been deleted?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, gcore

Programming on CentOS 6.6, I deleted an executable (whoops, `make clean`) while it was running in a screen session.

Now, unrelated, I want to `gcore` the process to debug something. I have rebuilt the executable, but `gcore` doesn't accept the replaced file. It knows the original file was deleted and won't let me dump core.

```
# gcore 15659
core.YGsoec:4: Error in sourced command file:
/home/dev/bin/daemon/destinyd (deleted): No such file or directory.
gcore: failed to create core.15659

# ls -l /proc/15659/exe
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Mar 12 21:33 /proc/15659/exe -> /home/dev/bin/daemon/destinyd (deleted)

# ln -s /proc/15659/exe /home/dev/bin/daemon/destinyd
ln: creating symbolic link `/home/dev/bin/daemon/destinyd': File exists

# rm /proc/15659/exe
rm: remove symbolic link `/proc/15659/exe'? y
rm: cannot remove `/proc/15659/exe': Permission denied
```

[FreeBSD's `gcore`](http://gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=gcore) has an optional argument "*executable*" which looks promising (as if I could specify a binary to use that is not `/proc/15659/exe`), but that's of no use to me as [Linux's `gcore`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcore.1.html) does not have any such argument.

Are there any workarounds? Or will I just have to restart the process (using the recreated executable) and wait for the bug I'm tracking to reproduce itself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9974254/560648 looks similar but it's about attaching GDB (where you can specify executable path) rather than gcore. And, besides, none of the answers seem to match my observation that even `/proc/<pid>/exe` looks broken by the deletion.

Comment: I can't test this right now, but iirc you can `gdb -p <pid> /proc/<pid>/exe` and run the `generate-core-file` gdb command

Comment: Playing around with this, I figured out that once the file was deleted, the kernel literally linked the `exe` symlink to `/file/path/file-name (deleted)`. Renaming the file to `file-name (deleted)` changed the `file` output for `exe` from "broken symbolic link" to just "symbolic link". I wasn't able to successfully run gcore even then, though.

Comment: @jPlatte Heh that's quite funny

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite the output of `ls -l /proc/15659/exe`, the original executable is in fact still available through that path.

So, not only was I able to restore the original file with a simple `cp` (though this was not enough to restore the link and get `gcore` to work), but I was able to attach GDB to the process using this path as executable:

```
# gdb -p 15659 /proc/15659/exe
```

and then run the "`generate-core-file`" command, followed by "`detach`".

Then, I became free to examine the core file as needed:

```
# gdb /proc/15659/exe core.15659
```

In truth I had forgotten about the ability of GDB to generate core files, plus I was anxious about actually attaching GDB to the process because timing was quite important: generating the core file at precisely the right time to catch that bug.

But [*nos* steered me back onto this path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021096/under-linux-is-it-possible-to-gcore-a-process-whose-executable-has-been-deleted#comment46285733_29021096) and, my fears apparently unfounded, GDB was able to produce a lovely `core.15659` for me.